# checking the existence of multiple arguments in an elegant manner

Tags: javascript, function, methods

I have a function that is like this -

```
var myFunction  = function(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7){
    if(typeof arg1 != 'undefined' && typeof arg2 attributeId != 'undefined' && typeof arg3 != 'undefined'){ //and so on for all the arguments
    //do something with all of the arguments
    }
}
```

Basically, I'm checking if all 7 of the arguments exist before doing something.

This looks ugly and is unreadable. Can you suggest a more elegant way to achieve the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use the `arguments` variable to determine how many arguments were passed

```
if (arguments.length !== 7) {
  ...
}
```

However this still won't tell you that all of them are defined values.  In order to determine if they are all defined you must individually check them as it's legal to pass undefined in the middle of an argument list

```
myFunction(1, 2, undefined, 4, 5, 6, 7);
```

Probably the best approach is to abstract this out to a separate function

```
var allDefined = function(args) {
  var i = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if (typeof args[i] === 'undefined') {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

var myFunction  = function(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, arg6, arg7) {
  if (arguments.length === 7 && allDefined(arguments)) {
    // They're all there
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arguments.length` to get the number of arguments actually passed.

`arguments` is an "array-like" builtin.  If you want to test whether the arguments have values, just loop over it as you would any array.  (Of course, you might deem a "query" method from a framework more elegant, but ultimately, someone's looping.)

Answer (score 0):

Every function has access to the `arguments` pseudo-array, which contains all of the arguments that were passed in.

If you want to make sure you have 7 arguments that are non null, then the check would look something like this:

```
if (arguments.length != 7 || ![].slice.call(arguments, 0, 7).every(
       function(val) { return val != null; })) {

       alert("Please pass 7 good arguments");
       return;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Su9s6/)

(to support older browsers you'll want to grab a shim for the `every` method, which for some reason I'm not seeing on MDN)

Answer (score 0):

```
var myFunction= function(){
    var i= 7, a= arguments;
    while(i){
        if(a[--i]== undefined) return new Error('Expected 7 arguments')
    }
    return a.length;
    //the first 7 arguments are not null or undefined
    // they could be false, '', 0 or NaN
}
myFunction(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, '', 7)
/*  returned value: (Number)
7
*/
myFunction(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, null, 7)

/*  returned value: (Error)
Error: Expected 7 arguments
*/
```